# how do i properly protect get method in php

Tags: php, mysql, get, sql-injection

i have this code

```
<?php 

if(isset($_GET['qry'])) {

  echo $_GET['qry']; 

}

else if(isset($_GET['ct'])) {

  echo $_GET['ct']; 

}

else if(isset($_GET['sct'])) {

  echo $_GET['sct']; 

}

else if(isset($_GET['brand'])) {

  echo $_GET['brand']; 

} 
else {

 echo "";

}

?>
```

how do i properly protect the value i get from the page url from sql injection or other things since i use the value on the page or database.

I have searched and am seeing different method, please which do you think is the best way.